# Combine a variable and string and get the value of the variable formed in a single line

Tags: bash, shell

I was writing a script where I came across a situation.

```
Audio_Repo = "/src/audio_123";
Audio_ImgTag = "aud021882";
Audio_Enable = 1;
.....
Video_Repo = "/src/vid_823";
Video_ImgTag = "video9282";
Video_Enable = 0;
....


#Say proj_var ="Audio"
#it could be either Audio or Video  based on some conditional check
....
proj_var = "Audio"
....
PROJECT_REPO= ${!{$proj_var"_Repo"}}
#PROJECT_REPO should hold the value "src/audio_123"
```

But the above representation throws bad substitution error
I know that I could use a temporary variable as follows

```
temp= $proj_var"_Repo";
PROJECT_REPO = ${!temp};
```

But I have many properties and I do not want to use temporary variables for each of them. Instead I want single line substitutions.

Comment: The closest thing to a valid assignment in your code is `PROJECT_REPO=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `eval`:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

Audio_Repo="/src/audio_123"
Audio_ImgTag=aud021882
Audio_Enable=1
# ...
Video_Repo=/src/vid_823
Video_ImgTag=video9282
Video_Enable=0
# ....


# Say proj_var="Audio"
# it could be either Audio or Video  based on some conditional check
# ....
proj_var="Audio"
# ....

eval "Project_Repo=\${${proj_var}_Repo}"

# Project_Repo should hold the value "src/audio_123" 
printf '%s\n' "$Project_Repo"
```

- The code prints **/src/audio_123**.
- `eval` is dangerous, and should be avoided if possible.  See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).  In this case the temporary variable, despite the increased verbosity, is a better option.
- I replaced `PROJECT_REPO` with `Project_Repo` to avoid possible a possible clash with an environment variable.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).
- I've fixed some Bash syntax issues in the code in the question.  Spaces around `=` are errors.  Semicolons at the ends of lines are unnecessary.
- [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) issues some warnings for the code, but they are all harmless.

Another option is to use a helper function:

```
# ...

# Set the value of the variable whose name is in the first parameter ($1)
# to the value of the variable whose name is in the second parameter ($2).
function setn { printf -v "$1" '%s' "${!2}" ; }

# ...

setn Project_Repo "${proj_var}_Repo"
```

Using the `setn` (a poor name, choose a better one) function avoids both a temporary variable and `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Uses arrays, not variable names you need to manipulate.

```
Repo=0
ImgTag=1
Enable=2

Audio=(/src/audio_123 aud021882 1)
Video=(/src/vid_823 video9282 0)

proj_repo=Audio[$Repo]
project_var=${!proj_repo}
```